# Embedding FOP xml to PDF: why so slow vs CLI?

Tags: java, performance, pdf, clojure, apache-fop

My program uses web services for the data to create an xml file, which it then passes in conjunction with my xsl file to FOP to produce a PDF. Over the command line it looks like this:

```
$ fop -xml ./test.xml -xsl ./template.xsl -pdf ./test.pdf
Apr 22, 2016 1:30:15 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #1.
Apr 22, 2016 1:30:15 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #2.
Apr 22, 2016 1:30:15 PM org.apache.fop.events.LoggingEventListener processEvent
INFO: Rendered page #3.
```

All of this happens in a matter of seconds. However, when I use the same input and output files for my embedded (Clojure) system, following the example in the source code distribution, it takes around a full minute to render the very same PDF when I run it from my REPL. How can I get my embedded version up to speed with the command line version?

```clj
(defn generate-leave-pdf-faster [{:keys [xml-file xslt-file pdf-file] 
;; Nothing is faster yet. 
                           :or   {xslt-file (-> "template.xsl"
                                                io/resource
                                                io/file)
                                  pdf-file  (io/file "temp/fopout.pdf")}}]
  (let [fop-factory   (-> (.toURI (io/file ".")) FopFactory/newInstance)
        fo-user-agent (-> fop-factory .newFOUserAgent)
        transformer   (-> (TransformerFactory/newInstance) (.newTransformer (StreamSource. xslt-file)))
        out (io/output-stream pdf-file)]
    (try 
      (let [res (-> (.newFop fop-factory MimeConstants/MIME_PDF fo-user-agent out)
                    .getDefaultHandler
                    SAXResult.)
            src (-> xml-file StreamSource.)]
        (.setParameter transformer "versionParam" "2.0")
        (.transform transformer src res) ;; this takes a full minute
        (str pdf-file))
      (finally (.close out))))) ;; I had tried .close rather than a with-open wrap hoping for improvement, but no luck.
```

Comment: Have you ever found the reason?
We are experiencing the same thing with command line version vs. Java API.

Comment: I didn't really solve it; the problem went away with a reboot of my system. I am guessing the JVM instance or some of its resource had become bloated.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. Unfortunately, we can rule out this side effect in our case. The search continues... ;)